# CSS: How to make a nav menu with a sub nav menu directly below it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu now, that can be found here... http://jsfiddle.net/EUaNY/

Now I'm wanting to have a sub menu that's the same style as that one, but shows up directly below it with the sub items for that particular link.  Note that this menu is centered on my page with `margin: 0 auto;`, and the width of the page is `width: 978px;`. You can see this in .header-nav-menu.  Sorry if I didn't include something my CSS is pretty basic.  If you have any questions or anything I'll be happy to answer! Thanks!

BTW I would rather not use Javascript but if it's necessary that's fine.

Comment: Isn't this something that Google would give you dozens of results for?

Comment: I googled but I kept getting results for drop down menus from each item in the main menu.  where the sub items appeared vertically in a list. Perhaps I wasn't searching using the right search string... my apologies ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you wanted the sub-menu to appear on hover, but it's pretty trivial using straight CSS by adding these 2 classes:

```
.header-nav-menu li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4px 0;
    background: #3E0C0D;
}

.header-nav-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here's your updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EUaNY/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you would like each item in that header to provoke sub items to appear beneath it (either vertically or horizontally) there is no way to achieve this strictly with CSS. Sorry.

In this case, straight Javascript will be more complex than just tossing in a jQuery lib. Like this one...

http://www.webchief.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu/index.php